# Does a `git reset --hard upstream/main` delete also local branches?

Tags: git

If I do a `git reset --hard upstream/main`, will also my local branches be deleted by that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset` does not delete branches.

`git reset --hard upstream/main` says to move the currently checked out branch to the same commit as upstream/main, and to clear your staging area of any changes, and to overwrite your files with the versions at upstream/main.

Your current branch will be at the same commit as upstream/main, and any staged or unstaged changes will be gone.